# Git project on Google Drive not pushing to repository from different computers

Tags: git, github

I initialised and committed a project on computer 1, and set it up as a repository on GitHub. This project is in a folder on Google Drive.

I set up on computer 2 with the same username and email.

I presumed that as I had set the email and username the same, and the project was in the same folder, that commits would go to the repository when committed from computer 2, but they don't.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: When committing on computer 2, the commits go to the repository on computer 2. In which other repository did you expect the commits to go?

Comment: I just want to say that putting a git repo on Google Drive is a really bad idea.

Comment: mkrieger, because the project folder is on Google Drive, shared by the two computers, I expected the commits to go to the same repository. If it's the same folder, why is this not the case?

Matt - Why is that so?